# Use of undefined constant bloginfo

Tags: functions

I am a webmaster of a site which was made with WordPress.
I don't know PHP. I changed PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2. 
Since this change, I have an error on my site :

**Warning: Use of undefined constant bloginfo - assumed 'bloginfo' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /homepages/44/d313626673/htdocs/fcq/wp-content/themes/athlete/header.php on line 20**

I downloaded the file `header.php` from the site:

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="description">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo; ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php bloginfo; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
           <ul id="nav">
           <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">Accueil</a></li>
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order&exclude=56'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div id="header"></div>
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect:

```
<?php bloginfo; ?>
```

`bloginfo()` is a function, so you need to use parentheses `()`:

```
<?php bloginfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. With your help, i have solved my problem.